# Try catch Block inside a while loop

Tags: java, loops, try-catch

How would I use a try/catch block so the user can start right where they made the error in my program?

```
while (true) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter your amount paid ");      
        int payCheck = s.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println("Amount Paid: $" +payCheck);

        System.out.println("Enter your expenses");
        int expenses = s.nextInt();  
        System.out.println("Expenses: $" +expenses);

        System.out.println("Enter your tax percentage taken off as a decimal:");
        float taxRate = s.nextFloat();  
        System.out.println("Tax Rate" +taxRate);

        double totalPay =  (double) Math.round(payCheck - expenses)* taxRate ;  
        DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
        System.out.println( "Total Pay: $" +f.format(totalPay));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    }
}
```

Comment: you improve the your code format

Comment: And the question is..?

Answer (score 1):

`Try-Catch` can't work that way. Use something like:

```
int input = -1;
while (input < 0) {
    try { 
        input = s.nextInt();
        if (input < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter an positive integer.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter an positive integer.");
    }
}
```

each time you let the user input.

Comment: What if they entered the number -1 ?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt He's querying the user input for `amount paid`, `expenses` and `tax rate`. I highly doubt any of them should be negative.

Comment: Is that a good reason to just ask for another number without any kind of message? Magic numbers in your code are rarely a good idea, especially if they are also valid values.

Comment: I'm not going to complete the whole thing for OP, this is a small working sample. As I said, `-1` should not be a valid value for `amount paid`, `expenses` and `tax rate`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function like:

```
int readInt(Scanner s) {
   int result = 0;
   boolean isNumber = false;
   while(!isNumber) {
      try {
         result = s.nextInt();
         isNumber = true; 
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

And use as follows:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter your amount paid ");      
    int payCheck = readInt(s); 
    System.out.println("Amount Paid: $" +payCheck);

    System.out.println("Enter your expenses");
    int expenses = readInt(s);  
    System.out.println("Expenses: $" +expenses);

    System.out.println("Enter your tax percentage taken off as a decimal:");
    float taxRate = s.nextFloat(); //Here you must write a function readFloat  
    System.out.println("Tax Rate" +taxRate);

    double totalPay =  (double) Math.round(payCheck - expenses)* taxRate ;  
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
    System.out.println( "Total Pay: $" +f.format(totalPay));
}
```

Comment: Eclipse shows an error saying "A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions".  What type of scanner did you import ?

Comment: there's still a syntax error with the scanner

Comment: Put your full code. It's hard to  guess what's happening